# Using asynchronous data from one factory in another factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

I'm trying to use geolocation data from one factory in angular in another factory that queries a weather API for data. I cannot figure out how to share the lat/lng variables between the two factories, I know you have use $scope but I cannot get the angular-promise to work correctly. Currently there are static lat/lng variables. The locate function in the controller doesn't even print to console, I think there's something wrong with my promise function.

Here are the factories:

```
'use strict';

app.config(['$resourceProvider', function ($resourceProvider) {

    $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;

}]);

app.factory("geolocationService", ['$q', '$window', '$rootScope', function ($q, $window, $rootScope) {
    return {
        currentLocation: function() {var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (!$window.navigator) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    deferred.reject(new Error("Geolocation is not supported"));
                });
            } else {
                $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.resolve(position);
                        var geoJ = $scope.data;
                        //console.log(position);
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    });
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);

app.factory('weatherFactory', ['$http','geolocationService', function ($http, $scope, geolocationService) {
    //var currentLocation = geolocationService.currentLocation();
    var apiKey = 'd079ba76e47f06f2ea3483892f1b1d40';


    var lat = '40',
    lon = '-79';
    return {
        currentForecast: function(callback){
            var url = ['https://api.forecast.io/forecast/', apiKey, '/', lat, ',', lon, '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'].join('');

            $http.jsonp(url)
            .success(function (data){
                callback(null, data);
                //console.log("weatherFactory API Call: ");
                //console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                callback(error);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And here is the controller

```
app.controller('weatherCtrl', function ($scope, $window, weatherFactory, geolocationService) {
    //console.log(geolocationService.currentLocation());
    //var location = geolocationService.currentLocation();
    //console.log("location object: ");
    //console.log(location);
    var locate = function(){
        geolocationService.currentLocation().then(function(location){
            $scope.location = location;
            console.log($scope.location);
        });
    };
    var pollForecast = function pollForecast() {
            var commutes = calculateNextCommutes();
            weatherFactory.currentForecast(function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    $scope.forecastError = err;
                } else {
                    $scope.forecast = data;
                    $scope.nextCommute = findCommuteWeather(commutes.nextCommute, $scope.forecast.hourly.data);
                    $scope.nextNextCommute = findCommuteWeather(commutes.nextNextCommute, $scope.forecast.hourly.data);
                }
            });
        };

    $scope.init = function () {
        pollForecast();
        setInterval(function () {
            console.log('polling weather every hour')
            pollForecast();
        }, 1000 * 60 * 60);    //poll every hour
    }
});
```

I'm very new to Angular and would appreciate any help from the community, I'd like to be more active on here! Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

-MC

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **DONT USE $SCOPE IN FACTORY**, $scope is only available on controllers.

The solution for you problem is very simple. Have `weatherFactory` expose the lat/long by returning them:

```
return {
       lat: lat,
       lon: lon,
        currentForecast: function(callback){
            var url = ['https://api.forecast.io/forecast/', apiKey, '/', lat, ',', lon, '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'].join('');

            $http.jsonp(url)
            .success(function (data){
                callback(null, data);
                //console.log("weatherFactory API Call: ");
                //console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                callback(error);
            });
        }
    };
```

And then, inject `weatherFactory` into `geolocationService` and you'll be able to access lat/lon:

```
app.factory("geolocationService", ['$q', '$window', '$rootScope', 'weatherFactory', function ($q, $window, $rootScope , weatherFactory) {
    return {
        currentLocation: function() {var deferred = $q.defer();
            var lat = weatherFactory.lat;
            var lon = weatherFactory.lon;
            if (!$window.navigator) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    deferred.reject(new Error("Geolocation is not supported"));
                });
            } else {
                $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.resolve(position);
                        var geoJ = $scope.data;
                        //console.log(position);
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    });
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick repsponse!

There is a problem, it is still showing lat is undefined at:

    return {
        lat: lat,
        lon: lon,

Comment: It's still trying to call the weather api before geolocationService runs and finds $window.navigator.getolocation, therefore lat/lon are undefined. How do I have weatherCtrl wait until it's found before it calls the weather API with weatherFactory?

Comment: You need to use a promise with `.then()`

Comment: Would I use the promise in the controller or weatherFactory? weatherFactory is currently using a callback function so how would I convert that into a promise?

Comment: I phrased my response wrong, I need to have geolocationService run *first* so that weatherFactory has the appropriate lat/lon to use in the http request. I'm using a promise in the controller but lat is still coming up as undefined

Comment: the `currentLocation` function already returns a promise, so when you resolve the promise resolve it with lat/lon (`deferred.resolve({lat:lat,lon:lon})`),  and in `weatherFactory ` just call `geolocationService.currentLocation().then(function(data))`.

Comment: So when I try to use `geolocationService.currentLocation()` inside of weatherFactory I'm getting a circular dependency error `geolocationService <- weatherFactory <- geolocationService`. I understand why, but I'm not quite sure how to resolve it. Again, I really appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
app.factory("geolocationService", ['$q', '$window', '$rootScope', function ($q, $window, $rootScope) {
    return {
        currentLocation: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (!$window.navigator) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    deferred.reject(new Error("Geolocation is not supported"));
                });
            } else {
                $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.resolve(position);
                    });
                }, function (error) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    });
                });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);

app.service('weatherService', ['$http','geolocationService', function ($http, $scope, geolocationService) {
    var apiKey = '...';
    return function(callback){
            //Note - a better, more angularish way to do this is to return the promise
            //itself so you'll have more flexability in the controllers.
            //You also don't need callback param because angular's $http.jsonp handles
            //that for you
            geolocationService.currentLocation().then(function(location){
             var url = ['https://api.forecast.io/forecast/', apiKey, '/', location.lat, ',', location.lon, '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'].join('');
             return $http.jsonp(url)
            .then(function(data){ callback(null,data); })
            catch(callback);
        }
    };
}]);
```